# How to pass Textbox id in detailsview to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, computer-science, detailsview

I should pass the clientID of textboxes in detailsview in insert and edit mode (at runtime detailsview mode will change) to javascript like this:

```
$('#textbox2').datepicker({
    ...
});
```

How can i do that?Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using classes instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here is ,

```
$('#detailsview #TextBox2').val() 

For Example...

<div id="demo1">
    <div>
       <input type="text" id="txtOne"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="demo2">
    <div>
       <input type="text" id="txttwo"/>
    </div>
</div>

then you can find that  textbox like this..

$("#demo1 div #txtOne");

This is just demo it may help you to get idea that how its to be perform

or if you say that inside control will be change then you can also use by **class** or any **tag name** too..
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a .val() method:

If you've got an input with an clientID of textbox you can use the following code to access the value of the text box:

```
$("#textbox").val()
```

Comment: Thank you, but this case is more complicated

Comment: because the control is in another control and it will change and i must use some code like :$('#<%= detailsview.FindControl("TextBox2").ClientID%>')({...})

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
                       $('select[id*=textbox1]').click(function () {
                           alert("Hello world!");
                       });
                    });

Comment: onece you select the textbox you can get the value

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textbox1"/>

<script>
    $('#<%= textbox1.ClientID%>').datepicker({
        ...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi, please consider that textbox is in the detailsview

Comment: <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

```
<InsertItemTemplate> 
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

For this you can use like...

```
$("InsertItemTemplate #TextBox2").val();    


here, client side you can not get `**[InsertItemTemplate]**` so you can use that 
control render in DIV so in place of InsertItemTemplate you use Div like

$("div #TextBox2").val();
```